# Stratum - Connected (unsecure)

Tags: gpu-mining, mining

I am mining with Claymore CryptoNote GPU Miner v9.7 Beta - POOL Catalyst 15.12. I am getting the message "Stratum - Connected (unsecure)".

What does this mean?

Answer (score 1):

It probably means you're connected via HTTP, and not HTTPS. Theoretically, it means a malicious ISP or router in the middle of your path to the mining pool could replace your monero address with their own, or change your shares to invalid ones, etc. In practice, the risk is extremely low.